# hot spot over background image

Tags: html, css, background, dreamweaver

My web page has a background image, and a transparent gif overlaid with hotspots linking to social networks, etc.

Is there a way of transporting those coordinates so they work without the gif and just hover over the background image? When I remove the gif it obviously removes the hotspots and I cant work out how to change this (or if this is possible).

I'd like to do this when the page is loading.  Right now I get a little icon before the gif appears and it looks unprofessional.

I'm using dreamweaver.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some CSS tricks. Create transparent DIVs and position them above your background image where you need them.
Here is an example: http://www.position-relative.com/tutorials/tute1_css_bg_image.php